# How to break apart numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I've been trying to break apart numbers and for some reason, the multiplication in line 6 doesn't seem to be working.

```
number=list(input("Print number"))
length = len(number)
x=0
for x in range (0,len(number)):
  length = length - 1
  a = number[x] * (10 ** length)
  print(a)
```

Sample input: 123

Expected output: 100 20 3

Comment: why number[x] ?

Comment: use `modulo` (`%`) instead

Comment: `number[x]` is a `str`, not an `int`/`float`/etc. Python is dynamically typed (a name can refer to a value of any type), but it is still *strongly* typed as well (you cannot use a `str` like `"1"` where an `int` like `1` is expected).

Comment: Use `int(number[x])` instead of `number[x]`.  That will convert it from a string to an actual number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modified form of your function which works fine.

```
number = list(input("Print number"))
length = len(number)
for x in range(length):
  length = length - 1
  a = int(number[x]) * (10 ** length)
  print(a)
```

Output:

```
100 20 3
```

Comment: You should post a description of the solution/changes you are suggesting, rather than just "try this!: <code>".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
number=list(input("Print number"))
final_list = ' '.join(a+''.join("0" for b in range(len(number)-i-1)) for i, a in enumerate(number))
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
'100 20 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following

```
def break_number (num):
    num_str = str (num)
    num_str_r = num_str [::-1]
    output = ["place_holder"]
    for index, i in enumerate (num_str_r):
        output.insert (0, int (i) * 10**index)
    return output [:-1]
```

For example,

```
break_number (2120) # --> [2000, 100, 20, 0]

break_number (543210) # --> [500000, 40000, 3000, 200, 10, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner you can use:

```
[int(v + '0'*n) for n, v in enumerate(list(str(number))[::-1])][::-1]

[100, 20, 3]
```